# Pronunciation of "candidate"

Tags: pronunciation

Dictionaries generally show two pronunciations for the word *candidate*: /ˈkændɪˌdeɪt/ and /ˈkændɪdət/. Macmillan dictionary shows both are used in either [American](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/candidate) or [British](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/candidate) English. So does [Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/candidate).

What is the prevalent pronunciation of *candidate*? Which one is more used in British (and American) English?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's more than two pronunciations, depending on who's talking, how fast they're talking, and how excited they are.

It's normal to reduce a vowel to shwa /ə/ when it's unstressed, and even when it has only a secondary stress, like the last syllable of *candidate*. The faster and more excited the speaker, the more likely they are to reduce the vowel.

And to do other things. The first /d/ is frequently deleted: /'kænədet/, and the second /d/ is often reduced to a flap: /kændəɾet/. All of these are independent processes, and may happen together or separately, so all combinations occur.

The technical term for this is [Fast Speech Rules](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/itsraining.html), btw. It's a big topic in phonology.

Comment: ... and JeffSahol.

Answer (score 3):

I can't speak for the U.K., but, in the U.S., both are used often enough that neither would sound out-of-place or unusual.

[Forvo](http://www.forvo.com/word/candidate/#en) had six pronunciations (5 from the U.S., 1 from the U.K.), and both pronunciations were given.

I also went to YouTube and queried "CNN Candidate". The first two selections I listened to provided a sample with each pronunciation:

- at the 0:06 mark of [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R5938w60Aik), we hear **kandidāt**,
- yet 28 seconds or so into [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A8l25xTqqnw), the reporter says **kandidit**

<sub>By the way, I only listened to these videos long enough to hear a reporter say the word *candidate*.</sub>
<sup>I'm not endorsing any candidate, nor attesting to the validity of the content of these videos.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I agree with John Lawler that there's more than two pronunciations. They are not shown in most dictionaries because there are rules of how a word's pronunciation gets changed in rapid speech. What you usually see in a general dictionary is how a word is pronounced in isolation or when you enunciate it.

A good pronunciation dictionary, like the Longman Pronunciation Dictionary by Professor Wells (Wells 2008), gives five variants for the word "candidate" (used in BrE):

/ˈkændɪdeɪt/

/ˈkændədeɪt/

/ˈkændɪdət/

/ˈkændədət/

/ˈkændədɪt/

By no means this list is exhaustive.

However, Alan Cruttenden (2008) argues that **/ə/ in -ate is more common than /ɪ/**, and it's a part of a more general trend, which is becoming "increasingly noticeable **among RP speakers of the middle and younger generations**" (p. 108).

Answer (score 0):

/ˈkændɪdət/ is used in England.